How to run cron jobs in AWS ECS Fargate
I'm in the middle of migrating a dockerized application (Backend + FrontEnd) that currently runs on an AWS EC2 to AWS Fargate. The existing application has some Cron Jobs written into the env file in the following format and being executed in the backend container.
DATA-SYNCHRONIZE_CRON_ACCOUNT-CHL-STATUS=0 45 20 * * ?
I'm a little confused as to how cron jobs should be scheduled to only run in the backend service and how it is run when the containers are scaled out.
I'm quite new to ECS and have no idea how cron jobs work in the ECS. Would really appreciate if someone can tell me how this can be tackled.
Although I've found a few articles about Amazon Eventbridge, I'm not sure where to start.

You typically don't want to run cron in a docker container, although I have seen it done. However, if you ran cron in your main application containers, then as you pointed out any scaling out of your ECS task would cause the cron job to run on multiple containers at the same time, which is not what you want.
The best way to handle this on ECS is to have a separate ECS task that just runs whatever your cron job is currently running, and have ECS run that on a schedule, using ECS Scheduled Tasks.
You may not even need to configure another ECS task definition for this. You can probably get away with using your current task definition, with a Container Override of the command that the container runs.
